# Deleting a row from a section in UICollectionView doesn't seem to delete the associated header

Tags: ios, swift, header, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have my own custom UICollectionViewLayout that adds a custom header for each row in a given section, when I delete an item from that section I get the following crash:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance for -layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader at path  {length = 2, path = 2 - 0}'

This makes no sense to me. I just deleted the row at 2 - 0, why is it trying to request a header from my layout class?

This is the code where I delete the row:

```
collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
            self.trackControllers.remove(at: index)
            if self.collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: 2) > index {
                self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 2)])
            }
        })
```

Doesn't matter if the section is empty after the deletion, or if there are still other rows, it still seems to request the header for the row that I just deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I managed to figure this out here on my own.

Apparently the UICollectionView will keep requesting the same supplementary views until the delete animation is over. To get around this I had to override `indexPathsToDeleteForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String) -> [IndexPath]`. Now this stupidly doesn't provide us with any information of which indexPaths have been deleted, so you have to keep track on this yourself in `prepare(forCollectionViewUpdates updateItems: [UICollectionViewUpdateItem])`

Here's the code that fixed my problems:

```
fileprivate var deletedIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
override func prepare(forCollectionViewUpdates updateItems: [UICollectionViewUpdateItem]) {
    deletedIndexPaths.removeAll()
    super.prepare(forCollectionViewUpdates: updateItems)

    let newlyDeletedItemsInSection2 = updateItems.filter({ $0.updateAction == .delete }).filter({ $0.indexPathBeforeUpdate?.section == 2 })
    let newlyDeletedIndexPaths = newlyDeletedItemsInSection2.flatMap({ $0.indexPathBeforeUpdate })
    deletedIndexPaths.append(contentsOf: newlyDeletedIndexPaths)
}

override func indexPathsToDeleteForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String) -> [IndexPath] {
    return deletedIndexPaths
}

override func finalizeCollectionViewUpdates() {
    deletedIndexPaths.removeAll()
}
```

(Note that the only sections I have that have headers is section 2)

Comment: Thanks for the hint towards "indexPathsToDeleteForSupplementaryView". Quoting the Documentation "For example, when a section is removed, you might want to remove the supplementary views associated with that section." When I remove a section, I might remove the section header. I might...